# How to switch tab using a button on another page in Ionic2?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm not sure how to open the `tab2Root`, using a button from my `help.html` page. I'm reading the docs, but there's nothing about that.

**help.html:**

```
<button ion-button large clear icon-end color="primary">
    Shop <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

**tabs.html:**

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Products" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Cart" tabIcon="cart"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Account" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Help" tabIcon="help-buoy"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could create a function in the help.ts class which is something like this:

```
SwitchTab(){
  this.navCtrl.parent.select(0); //Selects the first tab
}
```

In order to thave the navCtrl object available you have to inject that with the constructor of your class:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
...

constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
}
```

Don't forget to bind your button to the SwitchTab method in the class like this:

```
<button ion-button large clear icon-end color="primary" (click)="SwitchTab()">
  Shop <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
```